# PREG_MATCH found chars in pattern?

Tags: preg-match

Is there a way to use the found occurrence within pattern?
i.e.

`$string='number23    cat99 dog23 car66';`

for example, i want to find words that has number 23.... this doesnt work:

```
preg_match('/number(\d{2}) (.*?)%1/si', $string,  $new);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Learning Regular Expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)

Comment: @Biffen did you read the question at all?

Comment: Yes. Twice. Just read it again and it still just looks like a code request. One with unclear requirements at that.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I well understand your need, but how about using preg_match_all:

```
preg_match_all('/([a-z]+23)\b/i', $string, $matches);
```

This will match `number23` and `dog23`